# Limiting total time (part) of an AppVeyor job / a program in an AppVeyor job

Tags: appveyor

A AppVeyor, Windows, job will last a maximum of 1 hour, this is fine, but I'm facing the problem that my program goes into an endless loop and will consume the full hour although the program should terminate within 1 minute. For finding the problem this is quite inconvenient and a wast of time and resources.

Is there a setting to limit the total job time or a way to limit the time of an individual command?

Comment: The situation of the general timeout (i.e. on appveyor level) will hopefully be solved soon in the appveyor setup. Open issue is still a possible timeout per command inside a appveyor job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Right now you can manage time limits for [private build cloud](https://www.appveyor.com/docs/build-environment/#private-build-cloud), but not for builds hosted on AppVeyor VMs.

We will expose this for builds hosted on AppVeyor VMs too, but setting it bigger that limit set by AppVeyor will not work. Your case (make is shorter) will work. Watch [this](https://github.com/appveyor/ci/issues/517) GitHub issue for resolution.

Right now we can set it for you, per request, but this will be account-level change, so it will affect all projects under your account.

Comment: After long search I found the problem. I think reducing the timeout in a general way configurable by the user (in the appveyor.yml script) would certainly be a big step forward.

Comment: This will be probable UI-only option as people might not want for someone to send a PR with YAML updated to new larger timeout.

Comment: So in the YAML script we won't be able to do it ( :-(( ). The YAML scripts are used to do automatic testing based on changes in e.g. github projects. So, at least when I understand the previous comment correctly, in daily use this would not bring anything. Wouldn't there be a possibility to check the value in the YAML file against the default setting for the project and when the value in the YAML file is  larger just fail the job or set the value to the default value? The possibility to have an unlimited possibility in the GUI would still be OK.